# How do I change https link to http heroku

Tags: http, heroku, https

I hosted a api on heroku but the default link uses https is it possible to change it to http

Comment: [Heroku recommends doing this at the application level](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls). What language (and framework, if applicable) did you use to build your API?